# Copy To Clipboard not working for generated content

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a Javascript function which generates dynamic content and I want to copy the generated address to clipboard but the code isn't working. When I manually run the function in console it works.

I have tried defining the variable in the generated content itself with a script tag but that didn't work either.

My Code

```
$("#crypto-container").append(`
                    <div class="card address-card">
                    <div class="crypto-address-text" id="clipboard_address">${crypto_address}</div>
                    <img src="assets/img/copy-icon.svg" class="copy-icon">
                 
                     <div class="card-copy-success" style="opacity: 0;">
                         <span>Copied! <img class="copy-check-icon" src="assets/img/copied-check.svg"></span>
                     </div>
                 </div>
 `);

  $(document).on("click", "div.address-card", function () {
    copyToClipboard('#clipboard_address');
  });
  
  function copyToClipboard(element) {
    var $temp = $("<input>");
    $("body").append($temp);
    $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $temp.remove();
  }
```

Comment: You're appending an element with `id="clipboard_address"`. Are you doing that multiply times by any chance? Because `id`s are supposed to be unique, and `$('#clipboard_address')` will only ever match the *first* element.

Comment: No this is a unique id.

Comment: I found a solution check out this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66120911/15205016

Comment: It's nice that you solved this but the code in your question works as intended, so the problem is code you didn't post. Which makes this question not reproducible.

Comment: Yeah, could be it's a 300 lines long JS file. And thank you to all for your time for viewing my question and responding.

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to work just fine.

Tested here:

```js
$(function() {
  function init() {
    $("#crypto-container").append('<div class="card address-card"><div class="crypto-address-text" id="clipboard_address">${crypto_address}</div><img src="assets/img/copy-icon.svg" class="copy-icon"><div class="card-copy-success" style="opacity: 0;"><span>Copied! <img class="copy-check-icon" src="assets/img/copied-check.svg"></span></div></div>');
  }

  function copyToClipboard(cnt) {
    var $temp = $("<input>").val(cnt).appendTo("body");
    console.log("Copy to Clip: " + cnt);
    $temp.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $temp.remove();
  }

  $("#crypto-container").on("click", "div.address-card", function() {
    copyToClipboard($('#clipboard_address').text());
    $(".card-copy-success").css("opacity", 1).animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, 2500);
  });

  init();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="crypto-container"></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot initialize the append function at a later time like that because of my code's logic flow.

Comment: @neo81040 it should not matter when the content is appended. I would be more specific than using `document`, as seen in my answer.

Comment: I did try your approach didn't work. But I have solved it now you can check the comments for the answer link to the solution, I appreciate your help though. thank you.

Comment: @neo81040 great. I hope you will upvote the answer if you feel it helped.